# Manage Eclipse view that got out of reach

Tags: eclipse, perspective

When I work at home, I usually connect a monitor to my laptop, fire Eclipse, detach its console view and put it on that monitor. Of course, probability that I would forget to re-attach that view back to Eclipse window when I shut down the laptop is ~120%.

When I start the laptop again (without that extra display), eclipse starts and console view gets out of reach.

Is there a way to reach that view and put it on my laptop's display again (apart from reconnecting external monitor)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is the only change that you made to the perspective you can go

```
Window -> Reset Perspective
```

If you customized your perspective though, this will lose those changes.

I would just save the perspectives you are using

```
Window -> Save Perspective As... -> "JavaEE CustomDualMon"
```

and

```
Window -> Save Perspective As... -> "JavaEE CustomSingleMon"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried what it will do when it is not visible but it might help:
press Alt + Shift + Q and C right after (that shortcut opens console view)